# How to store the database connection handle from sqlite3_open?

Tags: c, sqlite, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have wrapped the **sqlite3_open**, **sqlite3_close**, and **sqlite3_exec** routines from the SQLite (version 3.16.2) C-API in order to call them from a Fortran 2003 program using the ISO_C_BINDING module. I use the Intel Fortran 17 compiler (ifort) with MSVC 14 on Windows and with gcc on Linux.

My goal is to open the SQLite DB and store a pointer to the database connection handle so that I can use it to store/retrieve results as the Fortran program loops through its computations. The main program pseudo-code would look something like:

```
program main
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  use sqlite_wrapper_module
  implicit none

  ! QUESTION: SHOULD DB_HANDLE BE TYPE(C_PTR) OR A STRUCT OF SOME KIND? 
  type(C_PTR) :: db_handle

  character(len=:), allocatable :: db_name

  db_name = "test.db"//C_NULL_CHAR
  call sqlite3_open_WRAPPER(db_name, db_handle)       ! wraps sqlite3_open

  do i=1,n
    ...compute stuff...
    call sqlite3_exec_WRAPPER(db_handle, sql_stmt)    ! wraps sqlite3_exec
    ...compute stuff...
  enddo

  call sqlite3_close_WRAPPER(db_handle)               ! wraps sqlite3_close
end program main
```

I have defined the explicit interfaces to the wrapper C routines in a separate module. For example:

```
module sqlite_wrapper_module
  use, intrisic :: iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  interface
    subroutine sqlite3_open_WRAPPER(db_name, db_handle) bind(C)
      import
      character(kind=C_CHAR), dimension(*) :: db_name
      type(C_PTR), value :: db_handle
    end subroutine sqlite3_open_wrapper
  end interface
end module sqlite_wrapper_module
```

I'm not sure I understand the [official docs](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/sqlite3.html), but they seem to state that *db is a pointer representing the database connection handle, which is an "opaque structure" defined as `typedef struct sqlite3 sqlite3;`. I don't know exactly what that means (C programming is not my strong point). So I tried setting the C_PTR from Fortran as follows:

```
int sqlite3_open_WRAPPER(char *filename, sqlite3 *pdb) {
  sqlite3 *db;
  int rc=sqlite3_open(filename, &db);
  pdb=db;        // <---------------------------------This
  ...check rc...
  return 0;
}
```

At first, this seems to work. However, the pointer returns to NULL once passed back to the Fortran program, and can't be used in **sqlite3_exec** or **sqlite3_close**. Should I define some kind of `struct` in the Fortran program to act as the database connection struct, and pass that into the C routines?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention. Add a version tag to distinguish a specific version, but that is not applicable here, your question is fine also in later versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning a value (`db`) to a local variable (`pdb`) whose life-time ends with the function, use a pointer to pointer in order to make those changes visible outside the function:

```
int sqlite3_open_WRAPPER(char *filename, sqlite3 *pdb) {
  sqlite3 *db;
  int rc=sqlite3_open(filename, &db);
  pdb=db;        // <---------------------------------This
  ...check rc...
  return 0;
}
```

should be

```
int sqlite3_open_WRAPPER(char *filename, sqlite3 **pdb) {
  sqlite3 *db;
  int rc=sqlite3_open(filename, &db);
  *pdb=db;        // <---------------------------------This
  ...check rc...
  return 0;
}
```

or better yet, use `pdb` directly:

```
int sqlite3_open_WRAPPER(char *filename, sqlite3 **pdb) {
  int rc=sqlite3_open(filename, pdb);
  ...check rc...
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was the problem and the fix. As you suggest, I ended up using `pdb` directly. Funny thing - I thought about the scope/life-time and I could swear I tried this very thing before posting the original question... But, all's well that ends well!